# Which MySQL data type to use for scheduling?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, sqldatatypes

I want to record the start and end times of, say, movies playing at the cinemas. I need to store the date (e.g. Jan 1, 2011), start time (e.g. 9:00am), and end time (e.g. 11am). Should I used DateTime? I've seen some implementations wherein an INT is used to represent time in minutes (e.g. 0 = 12 midnight, 1 = 12:01am, etc.). I'm not sure if there is some sort of benefit to using INT over DateTime.

Suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

Expanding on the idea of using INT as described above, the table would probably have the following columns:

- date (e.g. Jan 1, 2011)
- start_time (e.g. 540 - to indicate 9am)
- end_time (e.g. 660 - to indicate 11am)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) or [INT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

I prefer to store date&time in unix timestamp (INT), because i can use it in PHP functions like `date`

```
echo "Movie will start at ".date("H:i", $row['start_time']);
```

And it's easy to manipulate with it:

```
echo "Movie will start in ".(time() - $row['start_time'])." seconds";
```

Current date and time: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

If you want to copy movies to next day:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE start_time >= ".strtotime("today 00:00")." AND start_time <= ".strtotime("today 23:59");

 // query..
 foreach($results as $row) {
    $new_start = strtotime("+1 day", $row['start_time'];    
    // insert
 }
```

Comment: Peter, what if I had several movies listed to play at different times of the day -- and then I wanted to copy those schedules for the next day? Would there be a datatype that would be preferable then? Wouldn't my approach using INT be easier?

Comment: No inherent benefits to using DateTime?

Comment: Of course there are benefits of using DT type. With DT u can use [Mysql datetime functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and you can edit your data directly in mysql workbench. But using INT is eaysier to use in code. It's up to you. (sorry for my english)

Comment: What about time zones, leap years, etc. -- what problems might occur when choosing INT over DateTime?

Comment: Yeah, in this case using `INT` will bring you benefit, cause it's much much easyier to handle time zones etc. using `INT` timestamp than using `DATETIME` type . But in this case u can't use `mysql date&time functions, and your table looks very ugly:(`  And as i said - it's up to you what datatype you will use. I prefer `INT`. But `DATETIME` it's good choice as well. IMO In PHP `INT` is better. In other languages `DATETIME` is much better. And it depends what you want to do with it. Choice is yours.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion a person should use the datatype that better fits and describes the reality. In this case I would like to use `Datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

For me better is to use to DateTime columns, because INT have hidden interpretation. Without documentation you don't know what is it really: second, minutes, months, ...
It is only design approach.

When using DATETIME for start and end fields take into consideration that you may have trouble when "calculationg how long process take", because you should also think about timezones, daylight saving, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'timestamp' for both columns.

Datetime uses 4 bytes whereas Timestamp uses 8 bytes therefore more efficient.

Comparisons of timestamps is significantly faster than of datetimes.

When it comes to time zones leap years and daylight saving you may run into trouble with the int technique as you will have to take those changes into account manually.  Maybe this won't be an issue for you.

Comment: Hunter - how are 8 bytes faster than 4 bytes? Seems like I should pick the cheapest data type that will serve my purposes. No?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have two appropriate formats:

- "start time - duration" (datetime, int) or (timestamp, int)
- "start time - end time" (datetime, datetime) or (timestamp, timestamp)

One of the big problems with date-time stuff is the DST jumps twice a year, throwing off your calculations by an hour. Traveling between timezones is equally confusing. If you use the time/time notation, your duration may vary. If you use the time/duration notation, your end time may vary. Whichever one of these two representations is the most appropriate therefore depends on your usage (you may need to use a hybrid approach).

For movie show times, I'd say storing a start time and a duration in minutes is the more appropriate format. The run-time of the movie is a given, the end time comes after the fact.