# Which MySQL data type to use for scheduling? (Part 2)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, sqldatatypes

Part 1: [Which MySQL data type to use for scheduling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944676/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-scheduling)

In Part 1 of my question, I asked which MySQL data type to use for, say, scheduling movies at a cinema. When scheduling a movie, you need to know the date (e.g. Jan 1, 2011) and time (e.g. 9:00 am). Please don't discuss part 1 of my question here.

Here's my part 2: what if I wanted to store a cinemas daily hours of operation? For example:

- Monday, 9am - 9pm
- Tuesday, 9am - 5pm
- etc.

What is a good way to represent this in the database? Keep in mind that, in this case, the date does not matter (e.g. I don't need to know what date the particular Monday is on). I only case about days of the week and times of the day.

Here's how I would probably do it:

```
TABLE: schedule
- schedule_id
- day (ENUM: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
- start_time (INT)
- end_time (INT)
```

`start_time` and `end_time` would represent the number of minutes since midnight. So, `0` for midnight, `1` for 12:01 am, `2` for 12:02 am, and so on.

**Am I approaching this right? Suggestions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944676/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-scheduling/7944690#7944690) to your first question, in my opinion a person should use the datatype that better fits and describes the reality. In this case I would like to use [`Time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) type for the `start_time` and `end_time` fields.

Instead for the `day` field I would like to use numbers from 1 to 7.

Comment: Hi Aurelio, I'm just careful not to get into data types I don't fully understand. So, in my proposed table design, you suggest I just replace the 2 `INT`s with `Time`? The ENUM for `day` is OK?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I update my answer. Anyway, yes...I would like to change INT to TIME since that datatype better describes your needs.

Comment: Why do you prefer 1-7 instead of 0-6?

Comment: First because we are men and not computers, so we usually start from 1 and not 0. The second and more important reason is that so you can have the same index that will be returned from functions like this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: I like your second reason. Thanks!